# How do I edit the layout of the Person.aspx in a SharePoint 2010 MySite collection?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mysite

When logged into SharePoint and clicking the "My Profile" link from your name in the ribbon a page is shown (Person.aspx) and it shows data from the User Profile store.  This is great, except, we have custom fields etc that we need to show just under the persons name in Person.aspx.  I tried opening that page in SP Designer but that content looks to come from the masterpage (mysite.master) and then possibly from somewhere else as all of it has a yellow background color behind the text I need to edit.

Has anyone customized this page and if so what approach did you take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have to use SharePoint Designer.

To edit in the Design mode just click the right-handed arrow around the ContentPlaceHolder and choose "Create Custom Content" and it should now be editable.

To edit in the Code Mode (even if the content is in yellow), you need to hit the **Edit in Advanced Mode** in the Ribbon to get full access to the source.

Comment: I cant believe I missed the advanced mode ribbon button, not fully familiar with 2010 designer yet, and, I tried the other option already but I think a control rendering error prevented that option from showing in the little dropdown.  Thanks much!